# Import programatically images in Magento issue

Tags: magento-1.9, import, product-images, csv

I have created a custom script to import products from csv.
I succesfully imported **image, thumbnaill, and small image** like this:

```
# media gallery initialization
->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>[], 'values'=>[]))
# assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
->addImageToMediaGallery('media/import'.$image,['image'], false, false)
->addImageToMediaGallery('media/import'.$small_image,['thumbnail'], false, false)
->addImageToMediaGallery('media/import'.$thumbnail,['small_image'], false, false)
```

Now i want to import also a different images for: **_media_image**, and also set this values **_media_position** and **_media_is_disabled**

Does anyone know how to import this information?